# Accessing beyond 256 columns in excel using JXL

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I have an excel file an I need to write beyond 256 columns. The file is in 2007 .xls format. I see that I cannot exceed more than 256 columns.

On the other hand, if I try it with .xlsx format, I see that when I try accessing the excel file, I get a "Unable to recognize OLE Stream error". I read somewhere that this error is because of the excel format compatibility.

This seems to be kind of a chicken egg problem, and can someone help me tackle this?

Thanks
Abhishek S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this has to do with both the Excel file and JXL.

Excel as `.xls` (2006 and older) has support only for 256 columns and 65536 lines. ([Old limitations documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx))

These limits are increased in newer versions of Excel (2007 or newer, [New limitations doc](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005199291)), that use the `.xlsx` format, but the new format is exactly that, a new format. There are new functionality as well as new needs and new handling.

It should be no surprise to you that, unfortunetly, this also means that compatibility with `.xls` files does not mean compatibility with `.xlsx` files.

That's where JXL takes part. Not only it itself must be compatible with the new format (i don't know if it is), but it's likely the implementation is a bit different for each format.

I am not a JXL user tough (i use Apache POI), so you will have to research and sort out the possible solutions yourself, sorry.

Comment: Does Apache POI support .xlsx?

Comment: Yes, here is the quick-guide: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html